# Shortcut to return the cursor to the beginning of the word in text editor

Tags: macos, shortcut, text-editor

I know the shortcut to return to the beginning/end of the line but I'm looking for an alternative to Ctrl+(left/right)Arrow in Windows to go back to the beginning/end of the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Option-Left Arrow: Move the insertion point to the beginning of the previous word.
> - Option-Right Arrow: Move the insertion point to the end of the next word.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201236